# Snowpark Snowflake Python to run a sql statement and export to Excel

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm creating a Snowflake procedure using Snowpark (python) package executing a query into a snowflake dataframe and I would like to export that into Excel, how can I accomplish that? Is it a better approach to do this? The end goal is to export it the query results into Excel. Needs to be in a Snowflake procedure since we already have others "parent" procedures. Thanks!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE EXPORT_SP()
RETURNS string not null
LANGUAGE PYTHON
RUNTIME_VERSION = '3.8'
PACKAGES = ('snowflake-snowpark-python', 'pandas')
HANDLER = 'run'
AS

$$

import pandas


def run(snowpark_session):
  ## Execute the query into a Snowflake dataframe
  results_df = snowpark_session.sql('''
    SELECT * FROM
    MY TABLES
    ;
  
    ''').collect()
    
  return results_df

$$
;
```

Comment: Basically I'm trying to create a Snowflake procedure to run a query and write the results (export) to Excel file.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can do this by:

1. "Unloading" the data from the table using the [`COPY INTO <location>` command](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-location.html).
2. Using the [`GET` command](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/get.html) to copy the data to your local filesystem.
3. Open the file with Excel! If you used the CSV format and the appropriate [format options](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-location.html#format-type-options-formattypeoptions) in step 1, you should be able to easily open the resulting data with Excel.

Snowpark directly supports step 1 in the [`DataFrameWriter.copy_into_location` method](https://docs.snowflake.com/pt/developer-guide/snowpark/reference/python/api/snowflake.snowpark.DataFrameWriter.copy_into_location.html). An instance of `DataFrameWriter` contained in the `DataFrame.write` attribute, as described [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/pt/developer-guide/snowpark/reference/python/api/snowflake.snowpark.DataFrameWriter.html).

Snowpark also directly supports step 2 in the [`FileOperation.get` method](https://docs.snowflake.com/pt/developer-guide/snowpark/reference/python/api/snowflake.snowpark.FileOperation.get.html). As per the example in that documentation page, you can access this method using the `.file` attribute of your Snowpark session object.

Putting this all together, you should be able to do something like this in Snowpark to save a single exported file into the current working directory:

```py
source_table = "my_table"
unload_location = "@my_stage/export.csv"

def run(session):
    df = session.table(source_table)
    df.write.copy_into_location(
        unload_location,
        file_format_type="csv",
        format_type_options=dict(
            compression="none",
            field_delimiter="\t",
        ),
        single=True,
        header=True,
    )
    session.file.get(unload_location, ".")
```

You can of course use `session.sql()` instead of `session.table()` as needed. You might also want to consider unloading data to the stage associated with the source data, instead of creating a separate stage, i.e. if the data is from table `my_table` then you would unload to the stage `@%my_table`.

For more details, refer to the documentation pages I linked, which contain important reference information as well as several examples.

Note that I am not sure if `session.file` is accessible from inside a stored procedure; you will have to experiment to see what works in your specific situation.

As always, remember that **this is untested code written by an unpaid volunteer**. Always triple-check and test any code that is provided here. Please do ask questions in the comments if anything is still unclear.

Comment: Thanks! By doing that and using your suggestion I'm getting the following error: 
Python Interpreter Error: Traceback (most recent call last): File "_udf_code.py", line 53, in run AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'write' in function EXPORT_SP with handler run
I'm guessing it is because the sql statement I executed is no in a Snowflake dataframe?

Comment: @cent82 the error indicates that your variable is a `list` object, not a `DataFrame` or `Table` object. It's hard to say why that might have happened. As per the reference manual, `session.sql()` returns a `DataFrame` and `session.table()` returns a `Table`, so the problem cannot be because you used one of those two functions. Unfortunately, it looks like your problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: I was able to create the procedure importing pandas, openpyxl and xlsxwriter packages and in the procedure using the following:  'df = pd.DataFrame(results_df)
  df.to_excel (r'C:\text.xlsx', index = False)'  but now wondering if there is a way to export it into a file share or a local file system, is this possible? Because I'm getting error: in get_handle handle = open(handle, ioargs.mode) OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: 'C:\\test.xlsx' in function EXPORT_SP with handler run @shadowtalker